# How to set global defaults for reduxForm()

Tags: redux, redux-form

Does anyone know how to set global defaults for redux-form's reduxForm() HOC?

For example, say I would like every redux-form instance in my app to use the following option:

```
reduxForm({touchOnChange: true})
```

Maybe I'll need to monkeypatch redux-form itself but I'm not quite sure how to do that either.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this. But you don't need a built-in way to set defaults.

Simply implement a `customReduxForm` function, and always use it instead of the one from `redux-form` package:

```
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
export const customReduxForm = options => reduxForm({
  propNamespace: 'form',
  touchOnChange: true,
  initialValues: { userId: 123 },
  ...options,
})
```

Comment: Right.. I was hoping to avoid having to do this. Thank you for the suggestion though.